# create a new column containing difference of date taken from user and a column of dates

Tags: java, sql

i am trying to create a column with the no. of days between a user given date and dates stored in a column of a table in java using access database. here is my code.i am a new developer and dont have much experiance in this area. so if you find anything wrong with my code please tell me.

```
import    java.sql.Connection;
import    java.sql.DriverManager;
import    java.sql.Statement;
import    java.util.*;
import    java.text.*;

public    class DBTest {
public    static void main(String[] args)  {
// my code to accept a date from user
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); 
System.out.print("Enter Date: "); 
String ind = sc.nextLine();
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.mm.yyyy");
Date d = null; 
try {

d=df.parse(ind);

}
catch(ParseException e) {
System.out.println("Unable to parse " + ind);}


DateFormat df3 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.mm.yyyy");


String s3 = df3.format(d);


System.out.println("The entered date is: " + s3);

//my code to use that date and subtract a column of dates from it to get the difference   in days.

try {
    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:dbconnect");
    Statement s = conn.createStatement();

    String tablename = "datetable17";
    String createTable = "CREATE TABLE " + tablename + " AS SELECT DATEDIFF(day, " + s3             + ",SELECT EntryDate FROM MaterialsAging)) AS DiffDate";
    s.execute(createTable);     
    s.close();
    conn.close();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
}
}
```

Comment: Please show the stack trace if any.

Comment: java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error in CREATE TABLE statement.
 at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(JdbcOdbc.java:6964)
 at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(JdbcOdbc.java:7121)
 at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLExecDirect(JdbcOdbc.java:3117)
 at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcStatement.execute(JdbcOdbcStatement.java:337)
 at DBTest.main(DBTest.java:42)

Answer (score 0):

That code with the DateDiff function should look as follows: 
datediff('d',ColumnName,GivenDate)
the 'd' is days. If you want the difference of months etc then you should look up the symbol for that, probably 'm'. It can also do weeks and things like that, I believe.

Since your GivenDate is not from another field in the database , you might have to give it 'apostrophe marks'

This will give you the calculation GivenDate - ColumnName = number of days.
Hope that helps. I'm a novice myself and learned this stuff with a lot of trial and error (and a little stackoverflow help)

I also hear that the JDBC-ODBC driver is buggy and is not supported by java 8 so make it a priority to change the driver Asap. I've been recommended Jackcess and UCanAccess for my own java-MSAccess software